# Freeform get return value wether user recieve email or not

Tags: solspace-freeform, email

I have created form using freeform

> > when user fill-up form user as well as admin receive the email
> >     but admin want to receive another email whether user received email or not

for ex: while fill upping form if i enter correct email user will receive email but when i enter wrong it will not.
notification should be  regarding this whether user received email or not

freefrom send mail using  ee()->email->send();

i tried to get return value for this but it always return true if email is correct or wrong ee()->email->send();

Answer (score 1):

as I understand you want to be sure, that email which user is entered is exist.

First of all I don't know any EE add-on which which can do this. 
Because of email specific (as is - not related to EE) is no good methods to do this. You can do telnet request to the server, but this methods is not good for most free servers (gmail/yahoo/hotmail etc.), this may cause your server IP to be added to a blacklist and it will mean that you will not able to send email to this servers at all. Plus some server can have  "catch all email" setting and will not give you right answer.

p.s. only way to receive another email whether user received email or not is to setup admin email as sender. So he will get server answer on his email.